# Setting up XAMPP to run cgi scripts from web page windows

Tags: python, selenium, cgi

I am using python 2.7

I am trying to run a python script from webpage using CGI that executes selenium webdriver for some automation processes. For now I am trying to setup CGI by running a simple hello world script.

```html
#!/usr/local/bin/Python27/python


import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print 'Content-Type: text/html'
print()
print("hello world")
```

I have done configuration in httpd.conf "added ".py" in addhandler"

My cgi script is in the CGI bin, path is: "C:\xampp\cgi-bin\myscript.py"

In the web browser I am trying to run it by this url: "http://localhost:31337/cgi-bin/myscript.py"

Can someone please look and tell if I am doing something wrong? I really have to get this done soon but stuck here from long time.

Basically I just need to execute a python script by click of a button on web page. Using CGI is one of the options. If there is any other and better way that you can suggest, I can try that as well.

I am completely new to programming and have little experience.
I also found a similar question but I am stuck at the initial part of setup. 
link to question: [Running Selenium webdriver from a Python CGI script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45590237/running-selenium-webdriver-from-a-python-cgi-script/50301487)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How can _For now I am trying to setup CGI by running a simple hello world script_ related to `Selenium`? Am I missing something?

Comment: No you are not missing anything, I meant, eventually I want to run a selenium script using CGI but for now just to make sure it is working, I am testing it with a hello world script.